# JSF managed property

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6

I am a beginner in JSF and thank you for helping me.
I have 2 Managed Beans A and B.
I would simply like to recover 2 variables from the A bean to the B bean.
Is there a solution? I try for hours things found on the internet but nothing works!
PLEASE could you give me a start of solution?

I tried (but causes a null pointer):

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SessionScoped
@Named
public class AccueilManagerBean implements Serializable {
...
...



import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SessionScoped
@Named
public class NoteManagerBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{accueilManagerBean}")
    private AccueilManagerBean acm;

public NoteManagerBean() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() { System.out.println(acm.getPageHauteur());
}
```

Comment: I need to find a duplicate but in this case, since you seem to want to access a full bean, just replace `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{accueilManagerBean}")` with `@Named("accueilManagerBean")` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921324/managedproperty-in-cdi-named-bean-returns-null (not the right duplicate in my opinion, I might rewrite that a little, but all the info is in there)

Comment: You bean is a CDI managed bean, not a JSF managed one. This is a better one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390792/managedproperty-does-not-work-in-a-cdi-managed-bean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@ManagedProperty does not work in a CDI managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390792/managedproperty-does-not-work-in-a-cdi-managed-bean)

Comment: Replace @ManagedProperty(value = "#{accueilManagerBean}") with @Named("accueilManagerBean") : Error --> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Oh sorry typo... read the duplicate... `@Named` should be `@Inject` as a replacement

Comment: I'm lost. Please can you give me a complete example? Thank you

Comment: Replace `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{accueilManagerBean}")` with `@Inject("accueilManagerBean")`